# Screen display issue,

Tags: display, touchscreen, screen

My sons new raspberry pi works perfectly on his 26" monitor.
unfortunately it looks like this on his new 7" waveshare touchscreen.
I haven't got a clue, can anyone help?
[image]

Comment: What resolution is the touchscreen?

Comment: Welcome -- you should also edit into the question details about what you did to install this screen (if nothing but plug it in, write that).

Comment: Hi it's a 1024 x 620

Answer (score 0):

There is a limited set of resolutions available in RPI out of the box. You can't really expect any screen to just work without knowing that it's supported by drivers.
You can figure out which one works experimentally, or by identifying the screen (by its docs) and seeing if it's listed as supported. There is also a more involving options of tweaking the drivers yourself, which, based on my experience, often doesn't help.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In all honesty, after 40 years of home computing, yes I do expect stuff to work straight from the box ;)

Answer (score 0):

So, this is my reply from waveshare helpdesk.
I'm only posting it here in case it is any help to so.done else with the same problem, because I simply don't understand instructions like these and neither does my 9yr old son.
I plan to return it for a refund.

Your request (14474) has been updated. To add additional comments, reply all to this email.

SERVICE03 (Waveshare)

Dec 28, 2021, 19:24 GMT+8

Hello

Try this steps for work
How to use
This LCD can support Raspberry Pi OS / Ubuntu / Kali / Retropie and WIN10 IoT systems. When the LCD works on systems such as Raspberry Pi, the resolution must be set manually, otherwise, it will cause an abnormal display.

Please download the latest version of the image on the Raspberry Pi official website.

1. Download the compressed file to the PC, and unzip it to get the .img file.
2. Connect the TF card to the PC, use SDFormatter.exe software to format the TF card.
3. Open the Win32DiskImager.exe software, select the system image downloaded in step 1, and click ‘Write’ to write the system image.
4. After the image has finished writing, open the `config.txt` file in the root directory of the TF card, add the following code at the end of config.txt, then save and quit the TF card safely.

   max_usb_current=1
   hdmi_group=2
   hdmi_mode=87
   hdmi_cvt 1024 600 60 6 0 0 0
   hdmi_drive=1
5. Insert the TF card into the Raspberry Pi
6. Turn on the backlight switch on the back of the LCD.
7. Connect the Touch interface of the LCD to the USB interface of the Raspberry Pi.
8. Connect the HDMI interface of the LCD to the HDMI interface of the Raspberry Pi, power on the Raspberry Pi, and wait for a few seconds until the LCD displays normally.

【Note】

On December 2, 2021, the Raspberry Pi OS was divided into two branches, the Buster branch, and the Bullseye branch. The Buster branch is a continuation of the old system and is more stable. The Bullseye branch added some new features, using open source libraries and new interfaces. Since the current Bullseye branch has just been released shortly, it is not stable yet. If you are an industrial user, it is strongly recommended to use the Buster branch.
If you use the Buster branch system, you can use it according to the above configuration. But if you are using the Bullseye branch system, you need to modify the default KMS driver to FKMS driver for displaying the system desktop normally
Modification method: Open the config.txt file in the root directory of the TF card, find the following line:

```
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
change into

dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
```

wiki  https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/7inch_HDMI_LCD_(C)